# Service Fabric Actor remoting call results in "Specified cast is not valid." exception

Tags: exception, actor, azure-service-fabric

when trying remoting over actor in Service Fabric I am getting following exception: "Specified cast is not valid.".

My code is as follows:

Initialization of actorProxy

```
private static Uri serviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/ServiceFabricVoting/MyTestActorService");
private static IMyTestActor myActorProxy = ActorProxy.Create<IMyTestActor>(ActorId.CreateRandom(), serviceUri);
```

Calling of method:

```
 var number = await myActorProxy.GetCountAsync();
```

Actor Implementation:

```
 [StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
    internal class MyTestActor : Actor, IMyTestActor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of MyTestActor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actorService">The Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorService that will host this actor instance.</param>
        /// <param name="actorId">The Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.ActorId for this actor instance.</param>
        public MyTestActor(ActorService actorService, ActorId actorId)
            : base(actorService, actorId)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called whenever an actor is activated.
        /// An actor is activated the first time any of its methods are invoked.
        /// </summary>
        protected override Task OnActivateAsync()
        {
            ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, "Actor activated.");

            // The StateManager is this actor's private state store.
            // Data stored in the StateManager will be replicated for high-availability for actors that use volatile or persisted state storage.
            // Any serializable object can be saved in the StateManager.
            // For more information, see https://aka.ms/servicefabricactorsstateserialization

            return this.StateManager.TryAddStateAsync("count", 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: Replace with your own actor method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Task<int> IMyTestActor.GetCountAsync()
        {
            return this.StateManager.GetStateAsync<int>("count");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: Replace with your own actor method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Task IMyTestActor.SetCountAsync(int count)
        {
            // Requests are not guaranteed to be processed in order nor at most once.
            // The update function here verifies that the incoming count is greater than the current count to preserve order.
            return this.StateManager.AddOrUpdateStateAsync("count", count, (key, value) => count > value ? count : value);
        }
    }
```

And this is stack trace for exception:

```
"   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Common.NativeServiceCommunication.CreateServiceCommunicationClient(Guid& iid, IntPtr transportSettingsPtr, IntPtr connectionAddress, IFabricCommunicationMessageHandler notificationHandler, IFabricServiceConnectionEventHandler connectionEventHandler)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Client.NativeServiceCommunicationClient.CreateNativeClient(FabricTransportSettings transportSettings, String connectionAddress, NativeClientConnectionEventHandler eventHandler, IServiceRemotingCallbackClient contract)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Client.NativeServiceCommunicationClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()\r\n   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13.<WrapNativeSyncInvoke>b__12()\r\n   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)\r\n   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.RunInMTA(Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Client.FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactoryImpl.CreateClientAsync(String endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.CommunicationClientFactoryBase`1.<CreateClientWithRetriesAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.CommunicationClientFactoryBase`1.<GetClientAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.CommunicationClientFactoryBase`1.<GetClientAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport.Client.FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory.<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ICommunicationClientFactory<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Client.IServiceRemotingClient>.GetClientAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.<GetCommunicationClient>d__22.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.<InvokeWithRetryAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Client.ServiceRemotingPartitionClient.<InvokeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.<ContinueWithResult>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at VotingService.VotingService.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\mlani\\Develop\\ServiceFabricVoting\\VotingService\\VotingService.cs:line 148"
```

I am testing the application on local cluster. Implementation of the actor class and actor interface are default ones, which were generated after adding actor service to the project.

Thank you for any piece of advice.

Comment: I tried to repro the problem using your code snippets but I didn't get any errors. I did notice you create a proxy called "myActorProxy" and then call "myActorServiceProxy" - are you perhaps calling the wrong thing? Can you add your actor implementation?

Comment: Sorry this was just the mistake when posting the code snippets. I have added actor implementation in original post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, and out of curiosity, what version of the Service Fabric SDK and runtime do you have installed on your local machine, and what version of the NuGet packages are you using in the project? For the SDK and runtime, look for "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric" in Programs and Features.

Comment: I found out that I was using packages in version 2.3.301 and sdk and runtime in version 2.2.207 resp. 5.2.207. I tried to install newer version of runtime and SDK. But I am getting error during installation and I am unable to install runtime. I am enclosing link to installation log https://marekfilesstorage.blob.core.windows.net/public/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.3.301.9590.txt. First I was getting also error regarding unsigned device lease driver. This error disapeared after uninstallation of older version of SF but I am still getting error during installation.Please can u help me with this one?

Comment: Yeah that's a known issue with Windows 10 Anniversary edition. In the meantime, if you can't get 5.3 installed then you need to use 5.2 across the board, which means 5.2 runtime, 2.2 SDK, and 2.2 NuGet packages. The SDK and NuGet packages are not backwards-compatible with older runtimes.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem. I was calling an Actor service from a stateless service. The problem was that stateless service used a different version of `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors` nuget package. After I changed the versions to be the same, the problem went away.

This issue might happen when you have different version of service fabric SDK than you reference from stateless/stateful service.